# Merging two DataFrames - Multi-index ValueError

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, valueerror

I want to merge two DataFrames which look like the following:

```
df
                a        b         c           d        e        f
date                                                                  
2006-01-01  0.004503  0.006280  0.001777 -0.010202 -0.067004  0.062179
2006-01-02  0.004496  0.039818  0.035322  0.033956  0.017256 -0.024769
2006-01-03  0.004496  0.019632  0.015137 -0.008447 -0.061254  0.025879

df1

x              g        h         i         j          k         l
date                                                                  
2006-01-01  0.000001  0.000001  0.000001 -0.000001 -0.000001  0.000001
2006-01-02  0.000001  0.000001  0.000001  0.000001  0.000001 -0.000001
2006-01-03  0.000001  0.000001  0.000001 -0.000001 -0.000001  0.000001
```

I have had a go at trying to merge doing this:

```
dflist = [df, df1]
df2 = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['date'],
                                            how='outer'), dflist)
```

However, it returns the following error:

```
ValueError: The column label 'date' is not unique.
For a multi-index, the label must be a tuple with elements corresponding to each level.
```

Any help to fix this would be awesome!

Comment: Resolved issue myself:

     df2 = pd.merge(df, df1,left_index=True, right_index=True )

Comment: You can post your comment as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved issue myself:

```
df2 = pd.merge(df, df1,left_index=True, right_index=True )
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to join:

```
df2 = df.join(df1)
```